# Can I use 7/16" sheathing for LAN cable runner board?

Tags: electrical

New house with two teleworkers. I know the WiFi throughput is actually better than the ISP, but not depending on the daisy chained access points is a plus for me. Spoke to the guy who wired the house, builder ignored advice to run CAT 6 or 8 wire with the COAX. Coax is in the attic but the first part of the run is through a vaulted ceiling so the path can't be followed 100% at this point. I'm 64 and not light. The crawl space is easily accessible and I have glow rods, bits, etc. and a willing partner.

If I what I've read on line is correct and my own look at the 2020 NEC, LAN cable installation follows 334 Nonmetallic Sheathed Cable NM and NMC requirements. Exposed work in a crawlspace less than two 6AWG requires either a bored hole (in the appropriate place) through the joist, or a runner board. A little more work, but I've got a lot of 7/16" sheathing and can use that for runner boards.

Am I correct?

Comment: You don't say where you live, but typically low voltage (such as telephone, cable, or Ethernet cables) don't fall under the NEC so there are no requirements for how they're run.  If you have a specific NEC reference that you think indicates otherwise, please clarify with that information.

Comment: @Milwrdfan -- low voltage stuff is either Art 725 or Art 800 depending on what it is...but it isn't subject to most Chapter 3 requirements, so the rules *are* much more lenient

Comment: Don't get confused by the term low voltage, that's your outlets, lights and fixed appliances, LAN cables are classified as separated extra low voltage under the NEC.

Comment: Thank you everyone. Some possibly bad assumptions on my part and partly correct information from other forums. I live in WA State that requires a permit for any electrical work beyond basic outlet/fixture changes. So I'm researching what will pass inspection. An off-hand comment by my "leaving the profession" licensed electrician neighbor made me think I do need a permit.

Comment: It seems unlikely that a permit would be required for pulling CAT6 in a single residence dwelling. _Maybe_ for a commercial installation...

Comment: You would think. Washington state requires a permit for "Class 2 or 3 Low Voltage Systems"

Comment: Yep. Permits for LV now. City needs that dough ya know.

Comment: @Mazura State actually. The permit cost $72.70 for 3,000 sq.ft. to account for the run to the separate shed. State isn't making any money off of this. I'm having a separate garage/shop built. Inspector came by, that's when I was able to ask about the LAN cabling. Chit chatted, I've done some Habitat houses. Bottom line 1/3 of the holes were <1-1/4" from the edge in a 2X6!!!!!! He trusted me to get the plates and fix the licensed electrician's error, he's local and the inspector knows him, and signed off on the install. So you do have to wonder what they've seen.

Answer (score 5):

Spoke with a Washington State inspector. Short answer: Keep it neat. No hole, no span boards required for perpendicular cross joist wire.